Reading PDF metadata in Java using itextpdf 5.5.13.3 vs itext-core 8.0.3
I need to read some metadata from a PDF file. I have a code base on itextpdf library which does the job:
    static String getPdfFormVersion() throws IOException {

        InputStream inputStream = PDFVersionExtractor.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.pdf");
        final PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
   
        final byte[] docMetaData = pdfReader.getMetadata();
        try (final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(docMetaData);
            final String fileXML = byteArrayOutputStream.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
            final String versionNode = fileXML.substring(fileXML.indexOf("<desc:version"), fileXML.indexOf("</desc:version>"));
            return versionNode;
        }
    }

the library which I am using is:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.13.3</version>
        </dependency>

I would like to migrate to the newest version of itext:
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext-core</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency> 

But unfortunately the .getMetaData() method is not available any longer. I have tried to find an equivalent in the PdfReader class but without any success.
How can I extract PDF metadata using the newest version of itextpdf?

I have seen some example with PdfDocument but I read from the documentation that: "PdfDocument is the class that is used by PdfWriter to translate a Document into a PDF with different pages." Me i need to read the information, not write it.

yes but again it is used for writing not for reading. Do you have any examples where it is used to read PDF metadata?

I do not see getDocumentInfo method in 8.0.3 version : https://api.itextpdf.com/iText/java/8.0.3/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfDocumentInfo.html

Unfortunately I cannot also use the run pdfinfo! command etc. I am working on legacy project and want to update libraries to newest versions because of existing vulnerabilities.

I will try to figure it out myself, you had some good observations and links which gave me some ideas how to try to achieve it, maybe I will find it out :)

Thanks to  @K J comments I  have created a solution which seems to work same way as the one before:

import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class PDFVersionExtractor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String pdfFormVersion = getPdfFormVersion();
        System.out.println(pdfFormVersion);
    }

    static String getPdfFormVersion() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = PDFVersionExtractor.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.pdf");
        final PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
       
        // create pdf document representation from the reader
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);
       
        // read xmpMetadata from the document
        final byte[] docMetaData = pdfDoc.getXmpMetadata();
       
        try (final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(docMetaData);
            final String fileXML = byteArrayOutputStream.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            return fileXML.substring(fileXML.indexOf("<desc:version"), fileXML.indexOf("</desc:version>"));
        }
    }
}

What I have done is, I am using PdfDocument class in order to call the getXmpMetadata method. The returned byte[] seems to have the same information as the one returned by PdfReader.getMetaData.
